# How to convert datatype of all fields of struct in MATLAB to double?

Tags: matlab

I have a struct in matlab called ***mystruct***

It has the following fields with the following classes:

```
Field    Class
a       single
b       single
c       double
```

I want to convert all fields of ***mystruct*** to class **double**, but when I try:

```
double(mystruct)
```

I get the following output from MATLAB:

```
??? Error using ==> double
Conversion to double from struct is not possible.
```

Futhermore, I am giving ***mystruct*** as just an example. I realize I could just individually cast each field manually since there are only 3 fields in this example. I am wondering how do this this conversion to **double** for any structure in matlab with many fields and subfields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`structfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/structfun.html) for that:

```
mystruct = structfun(@double, mystruct, 'uniformoutput', 0);
```

Answer (score 5):

For scalar structs (`numel(mystruct)` is 1) the answer of Luis Mendo is probably the best solution. For other structs use this code:

```
cell2struct(cellfun(@double,struct2cell(mystruct),'uni',false),fieldnames(mystruct),1)
```

It converts the struct to a cell, then converts each element to double and converts back to a struct.